# Pulling data from firestore into flutter profile page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Flutter and have hard-coded a profile page using Flutter with values for profile image and statistics. However, now that I have designed the UI, I would like to pull data dynamically from the firestore database that I have created so that it automatically updates when there is a back-end change. As of now, I am not sure the best way to do this with the existing code. Does anyone ave any suggestions on the best way to implement this? Thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Profile Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Profile'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final String imgUrl = 'https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/selectall/2017/12/26/26-eric-schmidt.w700.h700.jpg';

    return new Stack(children: <Widget>[
      new Container(color: Colors.blue,),
      new Image.network(imgUrl, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
      new BackdropFilter(
      filter: new ui.ImageFilter.blur(
      sigmaX: 6.0,
      sigmaY: 6.0,
      ),
      child: new Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color:  Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.9),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
      ),)),
      new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(widget.title),
            centerTitle: false,
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          drawer: new Drawer(child: new Container(),),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new SizedBox(height: _height/12,),
                new CircleAvatar(radius:_width<_height? _width/4:_height/4,backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imgUrl),),
                new SizedBox(height: _height/25.0,),
                new Text('Nick Smith', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: _width/15, color: Colors.white),),
                new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: _height/30, left: _width/8, right: _width/8),
                  child:new Text('Instructor ',
                    style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, 
                fontSize: _width/25,color: Colors.white),textAlign: 
     TextAlign.center,) ,),
                new Divider(height: _height/30,color: Colors.white,),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    rowCell(343, 'Questions'),
                    rowCell(673826, 'Amount'),
                  ],),
                new Divider(height: _height/30,color: Colors.white),
                new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: _width/8, right: _width/8), child: new FlatButton(onPressed: (){},
                  child: new Container(child: new Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: <Widget>[
                    new Icon(Icons.person),
                    new SizedBox(width: _width/30,),
                    new Text('FOLLOW')
                  ],)),color: Colors.blue[50],),),
              ],
            ),
          )
      )
    ],);
  }

  Widget rowCell(int count, String type) => new Expanded(child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
    new Text('$count',style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
    new Text(type,style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))
  ],));
}
```

Comment: This will be helpful to get data from Firestore.https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: Thanks, Jigar. I have added the firestore dependency to pubspec.yaml but I am not sure the best way to implement it to the code in main.dart.